# How can I send/receive data to/from my samsung s3 to a (medical) device via an arduino board (wifi + usb)?

Tags: usb, arduino, android-wifi, medical

I am new to using arduino board.  I will like to connect my samsung s3 to a medical device via a an ardunio board.

The first idea is to send/recieve data to/from the phone to the medica device via usb on an arduino board and the medical device recieve/send data from/to my phone via usb on the arduino board.

The second idea is send/recieve data to/from the phone to the medica device via WIFI on an arduino board via usb and the medical device recieve/send data from/to my phone via usb on the ardunio board.

Thanks for your proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems, including this one are best approached in increments.  In this particular case, I assume you already have an arduino with a WiFi shield and a Samsung s3.

You don't mention the medical device or how it is programmed.  But first, concentrate on how to get the Samsung to talk to your PC via wireless.  In doing this you will learn a lot about how to write code for the Samsung and how to write code for a PC/Wireless connection.  There are probably already sample applications that do this.

Next, identify how the arduino board will connected to the medical device and make the same connection from the arduino to your PC.  Get this connection to work.  I know there are many examples of how to do this.

Next, get the Samsung to talk just to the arduino board which maybe turns on an LED.  Since you already learned how to code the Samsung to do wireless in the first step, then this step might be easy.

Next, connect the arduino to the PC and have the Arduino pass data back and forth between the PC and the Samsung.

After you have this "stack" of:  Samsung <==> Arduino <==> PC working then consider what it would take to replace the PC with a medical device so that you have:

```
         Samsung <==> Arduino <==> Medical Device
```

You can design your own series of incremental steps based on your more specific knowledge of the devices that you have.  But the idea is the same, each step is something easy to do and easy to debug.  But taking all the steps results in a complex system!

No one is able to do what you want on the first try (unless they have already developed the same or similar system).  But everyone is capable of learning new material, if they are persistent.

Please keep me informed as you work on this, it is an interesting project!!

Comment: I wish I could hire you. Please could you give me some support on how to do it?